# Can we use the fact that a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ generating of another vector space $E$ implies that $E = \mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the generated vector space $V=\langle(2, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, 2, 0)\rangle$. Let us show that $V=\mathbb{R}^3$.

To arrive at equality, we can use several methods, such as the exchange lemma, double inclusion (or single inclusion and dimension properties), ...

Can we also use the fact that the sequence $((2, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, 2, 0))$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and is generative of V to show that $V = \mathbb{R}^3$? It is indeed a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ : it is free and of dimension 3.

However, I can't find a formal argument saying that a generating basis of another vector space implies that the two vector spaces are equal.

Is this the case?

Comment: This follows immediately from the definition. Since $V$ is generated by $v_1,v_2,v_3$, $V=Span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and since $v_1,v_2,v_3$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have $\mathbb{R}^3 = Span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ so $V=\mathbb{R}$. (Note that we did not use the fact that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearily independent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with finite-dimensional vectorspaces, the argument is very cheap. For instance, if you have an arbitraty basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then you can just take the matrix $ M = (v_1 | ... | v_n)$, consisting of the the basis written in its collumns.

Since the $v_i$'s form a basis, $M$ is bijective and therefore a linear isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and itself. $M$ maps the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the basis $v_1,...,v_n$. This is called "change of basis" and immediately gives that the spaces are isomorphic to each other.